# Less than symbol

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, localization

I somehow lost the functionality to type less than (<) symbol on my keyboard. I've tried the on-screen keyboard, still can't type it.

Using Hungarian layout, the key is <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, other symbols work, but somehow this doesn't.

I have tried restarting and replugging the keyboard.

Comment: The M key itself still works presumably?

Comment: Does Alt+60 work? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3c/index.htm

Comment: @Mokubai Yes, it does work.
spikey_richie Yes, Alt+60 works too.

Comment: That's < ideal...

Comment: Is Windows still using the Hungarian layout?

Comment: @Burgi Yes, it's.

Comment: I also use Hungarian keyboard and `<` is typed by AltGr + Í, and that was the case for all keyboards I've seen so far. Could you post a picture of your keyboard? What happens when you press AltGr + M

Comment: @MátéJuhász there are actually two ways to type <, and indeed, one of them is AltGr + Í, but if you just check out your on-screen keyboard, you can see the second one being AltGr + M. Literally nothing, and it worked just fine till this point.
Can't post a picture of my keyboard right now, but just a picture of the on-screen keyboard.
https://i.imgur.com/XpFntbK.png

Comment: Have you changed anything recently? New driver / windows update...?

Comment: The only new driver was the GeForce Game Ready Driver, and no windows update before it stopped working.

Comment: Would using something like [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) to simulate pressing the correct key combination work for you? Then you could set up a script to press AltGr + Í (<) when you press AltGr + M...

Comment: @Mokubai if the problem doesn't get solved, it would work, but I mainly focus on fixing it.